# CSS is not working when accesing a view through controller

Tags: css, codeigniter, base-url

I am working with codeigniter. But CSS is not working even I use base url() function.

> **< link href="< ? php echo base_url(); ?> 
>   application/views/vehicle/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />**

If I just echo base url(), it outputs

> **http://localhost/codeigniter/**

My css is in

> **C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\views\vehicle\css**

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css file should be in publicly approachable directory. 
Application directory (`application` or `APPPATH`) is not publicly reachable. 
So your CSS file should be somewhere next to `index.php` file of your application. 
It is common to have `assets/css` path started in your website root:

```
-application
-system
-assets
--css
---vehicle.css
-index.php
-.htaccess
```

And if you make your web application code that uses CSS files dinamicaly regarding of route used, you can resolve it by adding more related subfolders:

```
-application
-system
-assets
--css
---vehicle
----style.css
-index.php
-.htaccess
```

This way, after `url` [helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#loading-this-helper) is loaded, you could reach css link with:

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/vehicle/style.css');?>
```

Eventualy you should include `assets` location in `.htaccess` file enabling Apache server to allow reading of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of the ">" closing tag before "media".

Maybe you could try with relative path. So use as many "../" as needed to go back into parent folder untill you reach root dir (if your php file is in a sub-folder) and then add the path to the CSS file.

Comment: Oh! it was a mistake done by me when I'm asking the question. it is not there in the code.

Comment: Edited my question to add possible way to fix your problem

Comment: Npz. Do you think I have done something wrong in any other place?

Comment: You should check the output code in your browser (Ctrl+U) and check if the stylesheet is reachable

Comment: http:// localhost/codeigniter/application/views/vehicle/css/font-awesome.min.css when I use this as the path, it says access forbidden.

Comment: The you should fix file permissions since the CSS is not reachable by the browser.

Comment: Can u please tell me how can I change that?

Comment: You should probably take a look at `httpd-xampp.conf`

Comment: I moved my css files to the asset folder and now it's working. Anyway thank you so much for your support!

Comment: Happy to see you fixed it!